# How to change Woocommerce single product page title to real product title?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

need wordpress advice. I searched for quite some time now but i can't find anything.

I am using organic 01 theme from xstore and i can't find any way to change the product page title to the real product title. Title should match the product .. now string 'Product Information' is written on all pages in that place.

I tried in **child theme** *functions.php* write php code but I didn't get it, couldn't even to remove the title for test purpose, which is very simple and i should succeed with remove_action(bla bla..) .. why is that?

In the beginning i just tried to change the title on all pages with the string in language suitable for the page but i couldn't do it either.

```
remove_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_product_title',5);
 add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','title',5);
 function title()
 {
    echo 'Produkto informacija';
 }
```

To better understand what I am trying to do I attach a photo
[image: To better understand what I am trying to do I attach a photo]

Comment: Its not clear whats real title and whats product title. In admin Main Product title which is display there. If you have other title then you have override template file or use hook

Comment: the problem is that i can't change the title 'product information' to the product title, which in this case would be 'klonavimo iranga'. 

i tried with hooks and it fails,hooks didn't even worked when i tried to initially remove the title altogether for test it and the title stayed in place....

Comment: if you dont mind can I have url please

Comment: do you have child theme?

Comment: https://hidro.e-vizija.lt/product/apsvietimo-maitinimas/

Comment: yes, i use child theme..

Answer (score 1):

You need to try with high priority

```
<?php 
// Frontend: On shop and archives pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'example_replace_title', 9 );
function example_replace_title()  {
    global $product;

    // Remove the product title
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );  

    $title = "My Sample Text";

    // Output
    echo '<h2 class="' . esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_loop_title_classes', 'woocommerce-loop-product__title' ) ) . '">' . $title . '</h2>';
}
```

Comment: Put above code in functions.php

Comment: it still doesn't work, i did something like that before, i don't know why the functions.php doesn't allow me to change the title ..

Comment: it was a stupid mistake! product information is not a title, it is a simple string that shows because the product title was removed! thanks anyway for your time! i just need more sleep :D